# Halve or Double the numeric Value in NumericUpDown

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, numericupdown

I've created two C# buttons in VS 2015.

How would I reduce the number value,and double the numeric value that's located in a NumericUpDown class with a button?

```
 /// <summary>
    /// place single bet, Low
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentSite.amount =((decimal)nudApiBet.Value);
        CurrentSite.chance = (decimal)(nudApiChance.Value);
        CurrentSite.PlaceBet(false, (decimal)nudApiBet.Value,(decimal)(nudApiChance.Value));
    }

    private void nudApiBet_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((sender as NumericUpDown).Name == "nudApiBet")
        {

            lblApiBetProfit.Text = ((nudApiBet.Value * nudApiPayout.Value) - nudApiBet.Value).ToString("0.00000000"); 
        }
        else if ((sender as NumericUpDown).Name == "nudApiChance")
        {
            decimal payout = (100m - CurrentSite.edge) / (nudApiChance.Value);
            if (nudApiPayout.Value != payout)
                nudApiPayout.Value = payout;
            lblApiBetProfit.Text = ((nudApiBet.Value * payout) - nudApiBet.Value).ToString("0.00000000"); 
        }
        else if ((sender as NumericUpDown).Name == "nudApiPayout")
        {
            decimal chance = (100m - CurrentSite.edge) / (nudApiPayout.Value);
            if (nudApiChance.Value != chance)
                nudApiChance.Value = chance;
            lblApiBetProfit.Text = ((nudApiBet.Value * nudApiPayout.Value) - nudApiBet.Value).ToString("0.00000000"); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show your code.This community is for helping in the code not writing your code.

Comment: @Saurabh srivastava Alright, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

To halve or double the [`Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.value(v=vs.110).aspx) of `NumericUpDown` it's enough to write the obvious divide or multiply `Value` by 2 and assign the result to `Value`.

But the result which you see will be rounded based on value of [`DecimalPlaces`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.decimalplaces(v=vs.110).aspx). The value will contain actual result, but the text shows rounded result. To increase accuracy of text, increase `DecimalPlaces` and set it to `2` or more.

```
numericUpDown1.Value /= 2;     // numericUpDown1.Value = numericUpDown1.Value / 2;
numericUpDown1.Value *= 2;     // numericUpDown1.Value = numericUpDown1.Value * 2;
```

Comment: JFYI, You can accept an answer by click on check mark near the answer. Also when you accept an answer, it would be great if you also vote for the answer by click on up arrow near the post. It's not compulsory at all, but it's common, reasonable and recommended. While you can accept only one answer, you can upvote as many answer as you find useful, including the accepted one. For more information about how does accepting answers work see this [post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming winforms:

1)navigate to the design page for your form.

2)double click your button, or navigate to the Events tab in the property window for the control and locate the "Click" event, double click it (the property window should be on your right, and contains a lightning bolt which is the events tab). This should auto-generate some code that looks like:

```
private void btnYourButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         //this is where your code goes
        }
```

3)Write the code to perform the desired function in between the curly brackets {}. something like:

```
numericUpDown.Value = numericUpDown.Value * 2;
```